# Construct matrix of ones and zeros based on sequences

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, integer-partitions

We are given ($a_1,a_2,....,a_m$) and ($b_1, b_2,....,b_n$) sequences with non-negative integers.

Decide whether it's possible and if it is construct a matrix $\Re^{m x n}$ of ones("1") and zeros("0") where the number of ones("1") in row $i$ is $\forall i $ : $a_i$ and in column $j$ is $\forall j$ : $b_j$

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understood, correctly, obviously not. Just let $m=2=n, a_1=3$. The number of $1$'s in row $1$ is supposed to be $3$, but the matrix is $2\times 2$, there isn't enough room in one row for three $1$'s.

Comment: Oh, wait, no sorry. The sequences are given. Updating question.

Comment: The problem still stands. We are given $(3,0)$ and $(0,0)$. The the number of $1$'s in row $1$ of a $2\times 2$ matrix is supposed to be $3$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this innocent-looking problem is a well-known and nontrivial result in combinatorics, the Gale-Ryser theorem (see, for example, http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Kutatas/EGHH/Gale-Ryser-Krause-1966.pdf).

Comment: That result isn't the same statement as the question.

Comment: Then I am missing something.

Comment: The given sequences, in the paper, must sum up to certain constants. This restriction isn't imposed in the question.

Comment: If they don't sum up to the same constant, then the answer is somewhat trivially no, because the sums of both sequences will be the total number of $1$'s in the matrix.

Comment: So we agree. See my comments in the question.

Comment: yes, your comment to the question is not off the mark - indeed such a matrix need not always exist. On the other hand, the Gale-Ryser theorem gives a necessary and sufficient condition for its existence for general sequences.

Comment: Another source is Ryser's book, Combinatorial Mathematics. It's in the MAA Carus Monograph series.